Eigenfunctions of integral operator.
Consider the following integral operator on $L^2 [-\pi, \pi]$ given by, $$K \phi (t) = \int_{-\pi} ^ {\pi} (t-s)^2 \phi(s) ds$$.
Finding the eigenfunctions for K has proved to be a little tricky. I first tried the standard harmonics $\phi_n(t) = e^{int}$ but quickly realized that the eigenvalue will not be independent of t.
Second, I tried differentiating the eigenvalue equation $K \phi(t) = \lambda \phi (t)$ three times and wound up with the equation $\lambda \phi^{'''}(t) = 0$. In general, the solutions to this equation are quadratic functions in t, but I'm not sure how to find the constants of integration.
Any help would be useful.

Observe that $$(K\phi)(t)=a_\phi+b_\phi t+c_\phi t^2$$ where $$a_\phi=\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi s^2\phi(s)\,ds,\ b_\phi=-2\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi s\phi(s)\,ds,\ c_\phi=\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi \phi(s)\,ds$$ Hence the range is three dimensional. The kernel of $K$ consists of functions which are orthogonal to $1$, $t$ and $t^2.$ The eigenfunctions corresponding to nonzero eigenvalues are polynomials of at most second degree. The function $t$  is orthogonal to $1,$ $t^2$ and $$(Kt)(t)=b_tt= -2\pi^3t$$ The linear span of $1$ and $t^2$ is invariant for $K$ and $$ a_1={2\over 3}\pi^3,\ c_1=2\pi,\ a_{t^2}= {2\over 5}\pi^5,\ c_{t^2}= {2\over 3}\pi^3$$ Thus the eigenvalues  of $K$ on the linear span of $1$ and $t^2$ coincide with those of the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix} {2\over 3}\pi^3 & {2\over 5}\pi^5 \\ 2\pi & {2\over 3}\pi^3\end{pmatrix}$$ Moreover an eigenvector $(v_1,v_2)$ of the matrix corresponds to the eigenfunction $v_1+v_2t^2$ of the operator $K.$
Remark Let $f(t)$ be the $2\pi$-periodic function so that $f(t)=t^2$ for $-\pi<t<\pi.$ Then the operator
$$(K\phi)(t)={1\over 2\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(t-s)\phi(s)\,ds$$ admits eigenvalues $\lambda_n=\widehat{f}(n)$ corresponding to the eigenfunctions $e^{-int}$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$
